# retrieve unique ID from aggregate function MAX/GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, function, group-by, aggregate

I'm getting an error when using an aggregate function. Hopefully you guys can help me, I explained the situation below.

In a football/soccer game a player gets a red card after its second yellow card. Query **qry1TwiceYellow** gives the unique ID of the players that have two yellow cards. The query is written down below and works fine.

`SELECT Player_ID FROM (SELECT Player_ID, Count(ID) AS Total FROM YellowCards WHERE Game_ID=29 AND HomeOrAway=1 GROUP BY Player_ID) WHERE Total=2;`

Now I want to retrieve some information about the last card:

- The unique **ID** of the last yellow card.
- **Minute** the offence happened.
- The **player ID**.

I wrote for this the following query but this causes an error (below the query).

`SELECT Y.ID, Y.Player_ID, MAX(Y.Minute) As LastYellow
FROM qry1TwiceYellow As q 
INNER JOIN YellowCards As Y
ON q.Player_ID = Y.Player_ID
WHERE Y.Game_ID=29 AND Y.HomeOrAway=1
GROUP BY Y.Player_ID;`

`Your query does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of an aggregate function.`

I tried the following as solutions:

- By adding ID to the GROUP BY the error disappears but the MAX(Minute) aggregate function is useless since the ID is unique.
- Leaving out the unique ID. Then INNER JOIN the Player_ID and the Max(Minute) with the complete table to get the unique ID. This works fine, until 2 or more players get in the same minute there second yellow card.

How do I solve this?

Thnx in advance,
Chris

Comment: What should happend when 2 or more players get a second yellow card in the same minute?  Should the query return 1 or all of them?

Comment: The query should return each unique ID of each second yellow card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query that selects all 2nd yellow cards for a game by counting the number of previous cards for the same game and player:

```
SELECT Y1.ID, Y1.Player_ID, Y1.Minute
FROM YellowCards Y1
WHERE Y1.Game_ID=29 AND Y1.HomeOrAway=1 
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM YellowCards Y2
    WHERE Y1.Game_ID = Y2.Game_ID AND Y1.HomeOrAway = Y2.HomeOrAway AND Y1.Player_ID = Y2.Player_ID AND Y1.Minute > Y2.Minute
) = 1;
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a536/2)

Comment: Thnx mate! This worked. Good to know that nesting a sub-query like this is also possible.